# R.layout shows only Android default template proposals.

Tags: android, android-resources, r.java-file

I have a couple of xml files in my layout folder but when I use them in my class the template proposals doesn't show my layout files but shows android default proposals. There seem to be no error in any of my files at all. I tried deleting the R.java file and rebuilding and restarting eclipse but nothing seems to be working. PLease help. I need to get this done asap :(

Thanks,
Sowmya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look are you setting xml name fine like

e.g

you have your.xml
Then in onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your);
```

Then clean your project.
if you have design multiple xml with same name then you must have to place them in appropriate folder using hdpi etc
[Further details available here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

This may be because, when you try to use your `xml` layouts, the default android R file is imported.

```
import com.android.R
```

Check that. If it is there, delete that import and import the correct `R file` which starts with your package name.

Comment: Tried this. Thanks:) Apparently If I put the Activity in a new package it doesn't show the resources, if I use one single package it does show up. Now my package is getting bulky. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

or you can write

```
import.R.layout
```

It will work for sure